# I eventually lost some data in Firebase Analytics console

Tags: firebase-analytics

I logged an event named `LV_COMPLETE` with 3 custom parameters `STAR1` `STAR2` `STAR3`
It worked perfectly on Dec. 24, and i've around 11k events logged then.

But today when i revisited that date range, all the data in the custom parameters were gone.

Does anybody encountered the same issue? How can I get my history data back?

[image]